# Unable to open/import existing project into Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm a beginner at Android and there's an existing Android project I'd like to import into Eclipse.
From googling I found I should do this via File/Import/Existing project, which I did (there is a .project file in the root directory of the project I wish to open).

However after doing this Eclipse displayed an error message saying:

"ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Users\ ..... \R.java: No such file or directory"

However the file R.java does exist at the location Eclipse is displaying in the error message.
Why does it think the file isn't there when it is?
How can I proceed to open the project?

TIA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to `Clean` your project and then `Rebuild` it. You could also try to manually delete the `R.java` file and `Rebuild` your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the project but after I cleaned the project I wasn't able to import the same project back to the same workspace.  I think some files got deleted from the cleaning process.

I ended up changing the workspace directory and was able to get it working again.